Relation between two series with equal sum of series
In the series S = $\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ + $\frac{x^2}{1-x^4}$ + $\frac{x^4}{1-x^8}$+ ....$\infty$ by solving it by method of difference($V_n - V_{n-1}$) we get S = $\frac{x}{1-x}$.
Also, we know that Sum of the following GP is also same:  $x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4....\infty = \frac{x}{1-x}$
(In both the cases, $|x|<1$)
Then how are both the series related to each other? How can we convert the first series to the second one?

The second one is only true if $-1<x<1$.

Yes thanks for correction. i made the edit

All good. What happens if you try to sum the first series by telescoping? Does that give any hints?

Yes the terms cancel out leaving only 1st term and last term which i solved by limits

With $|x|<1$ you can say that the Taylor series of the terms in the first expression are:

$\frac{x}{1-x^2} = x+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^9+x^{11}+\cdots$

$\frac{x^2}{1-x^4} = x^2+x^6+x^{10}+\cdots$

$\frac{x^4}{1-x^8} = x^4+x^{12}+\cdots$

$\frac{x^8}{1-x^{16}} = x^8+\cdots$

etc.


and summing these gives $$x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8+x^9+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+\cdots$$ i.e. the second expression, the Taylor series of $\frac{x}{1-x}$.
It is not difficult to formalise this.

yess, cool thanks
